Whats needed to be changed if I'm moving SSRS DBs from a prod env to a test one?
I’m a bit confused on how I move the reporting database (and the temp one) from prod to test.
I know after moving DBs I need to export its encryption key, but I would like to not cause any report to be sent by mistake to prod clients. Is there a way to clean the subscription table for example, without breaking the reporting service?

You can disable SQL Agent. All subs are fired by SQL agent

Oh sure, sorry yeah this part I'm aware. but we have other jobs in that server that needs to keep running. and it's also more for a little more knowledge. I know the Subscriptions table hold subscriptions, so, would I be able to for safety, rename it to _old for example and recreate another Subscriptions one ?

Deleting the subscriptions should be fine (in fact, there's a stored proc in the database for deleting subscriptions, but you can see that's pretty basic - except that it also calls a secondary proc related to the "SubscriptionsBeingDeleted" table).  I certainly would never recommend doing manual deletes like this in a LIVE environment, but for your TEST environment the worst that can happen is that you do something not quite right and need to restore the database again and retry

oh sure ! yes this is TEST. I actually moved the subscriptions to a _OLD table and tried to trucante the original one and I noticed we have a FK on it. with the procedure you mentioned, I'm able to clean this table automatically? I never heard of it, so I will take a look !

(Can't edit after 5min )
everything I found relates going to the Web portal, I would like to try cleaning it from SSMS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/create-and-manage-subscriptions-for-native-mode-report-servers?view=sql-server-ver16
I found 2 procs (DeleceSubs and DeleteActive). checking them.

FYI: I could clean the Subscriptions table with the DeleteSubscription proc. thanks all ! (waiting to see if someone gets a more complex answer for me to accept )

Another approach would be to disable jobs related to subscriptions. get job name from Subscription guid is not straightforward but possible.
